# How do I create a new variable (in a covid dataset) that keeps track of number of days passed since a country hit 1000 cases

Tags: r

I have a covid dataset like below

[image]

In some countries the virus has been spreading for longer than in others. As a result, some countries have a larger number of cases than others just because they are “further ahead on the curve”. To compare how one country (e.g, the UK) is doing compared to other countries where the disease has been going on for longer (e.g., Italy) it might be helpful to measure time as days since first recording x number of cases per day (where x
could be 1000). In this normalized time scale day 0 is the first day that a country recorded 1000 cases. Create a new variable that keeps track of number of days passed since a country hit 1000 cases.

Comment: Hi kris, welcome to SO. it would be helpful if you could create a minimal, reproducible example (reprex) and edit your post - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - that way others can generate the data, manipulate it as needed, and provide support. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to find the first occurrence of at least 1000 new cases per date and location. Using dplyr, I'd write a function that does exactly that.

First a reprex based on your data.

```
df <- data.frame(
  location = c("Spain", "Spain", "Kyrgyzstan", "Kyrgyzstan"),
  date = as.Date(c(
    "2020-05-28", "2020-05-29", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-22"
  )),
  total_cases = c(237906, 238564, 42703, 42889),
  new_cases = c(1647,-372, 196, 186)
)
```

Then a function that finds and counts the time between the previous occurrence of at least 1000 cases, given a date and location.

```
days_since_1000_cases <- function(loc, dat) {
  df_filtered <- df %>%
    filter(
      location == loc, 
      date <= dat, 
      new_cases >= 1000) %>%
    # Order on the dates and pick the first as that was the previous occurence
    arrange(date) %>% 
    head(1)

  if (nrow(df_filtered) > 0) {
    return(dat - df_filtered$date)
  }
  return(NA)
}
```

And finally, using the function on the data leads to

```
df %>%
  group_by(location, date) %>%
  mutate(days_since = days_since_1000_cases(location, date))

# A tibble: 4 × 5
# Groups:   location, date [4]
  location   date       total_cases new_cases days_since
  <fct>      <date>           <dbl>     <dbl> <drtn>    
1 Spain      2020-05-28      237906      1647  0 days   
2 Spain      2020-05-29      238564      -372  1 days   
3 Kyrgyzstan 2020-08-21       42703       196 NA days   
4 Kyrgyzstan 2020-08-22       42889       186 NA days
```

Comment: do you think it's should be new_cases >= 1000 or total_cases?

Comment: Per your question " it might be helpful to measure time as days since first recording x number of cases per day", it is clearly new_cases. Total cases can only once exceed 1000 and would result in total days since to always revert to the same day, resulting in days_since to always being 0 if total_cases >= 1000 or NA if not.